# SQL*Plus 'crashes' with insert query on remote connection

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

We have two CentOS 6.2 machines. One running Oracle 11g2 and the other running our own custom software. The software calls SQL*Plus from the commandline to execute a series of queries. One of these queries makes SQL*Plus crash not giving out any warning/error, just going straight to command line and exit with code 1.

I've tried to run this query manually from SQL*Plus, same problem. I've tried to run it on the database server locally and it just works.

The setup on the machine running our own software:
I've copied $ORACLE_HOME contents from database server.
Set ORACLE_HOME to that path
Set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to $ORACLE_HOME/lib
Set PATH to $PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin

SQL*Plus call works perfectly, just not with that certain kind of query. Any suggestions?

```
insert into DPF_RT_DATA_ANALYSIS (
run_id,
entity_name,
table_state,
state_type,
column_name,
ctype,
function,
step,
value,
occurences
)
select 
'&RUN_ID',
'MUT_BAG_WPL_GMT',
'ANALYSIS_MUT_BAG_WPL_GMT',
'ANALYSIS',
'WOONPLAATS',
'Varchar2',
'MIN_FREQ',
step,
value,
occ
from (
select rownum step, colname value, freq occ
from (
select WOONPLAATS colname, count(WOONPLAATS) freq
from MUT_BAG_WPL_GMT
group by WOONPLAATS
order by freq asc
) where rownum <= 20
);
```

Anyone has run into this problem or has any suggestions on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: It's probably the `'&RUN_ID'` causing SQL*Plus to think it needs to prompt. Are you setting it earlier in the script?

Comment: Yea, Thats not the problem... Working in earlier queries

Comment: I believe the issue is more related to libraries / path settings than there's a problem with the query since it runs anywhere but sqlplus.

Answer (score 0):

Try aliasing your derived tables, e g.:

```
insert into DPF_RT_DATA_ANALYSIS (
    run_id,
    entity_name,
    table_state,
    state_type,
    column_name,
    ctype,
    function,
    step,
    value,
    occurences
    )
select '&RUN_ID',
    'MUT_BAG_WPL_GMT',
    'ANALYSIS_MUT_BAG_WPL_GMT',
    'ANALYSIS',
    'WOONPLAATS',
    'Varchar2',
    'MIN_FREQ',
    step,
    value,
    occ
from (
    select rownum step,
        colname value,
        freq occ
    from (
        select WOONPLAATS colname,
            count(WOONPLAATS) freq
        from MUT_BAG_WPL_GMT
        group by WOONPLAATS
        order by freq asc
        ) a
    where rownum <= 20
    ) b;
```

Comment: But shouldn't it generate an error? All code works perfectly in SQLDeveloper and SQL*Plus 10

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to a bug in SQL*Plus 11.2.0.1.0... We've updated to 11.2.0.3.0 and our problems seemed to have disappeared.